# What is the best practice with React for importing a large static array to use in a select field?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, import

The situation is fairly simple. I have a single array of over 2500 strings of company names, which
is being stored locally in the project as a JSON file in a subdirectory under `src`. Currently I am importing the JSON file in the component I'm using it for as a variable in the standard React fashion, i.e `import arrayOfNames from "Assets/names/names.json`.

At the moment I am using material-ui's "Autocomplete" text component to populate a dropdown list of 10 items from that array at a time depending on the user's text input. So far storing it locally provides a very quick response on user input with no lag, which is the crucial factor.

What I want to know is: Is it considered a bad practice to store this array locally, where webpack will inevitably bundle it with the rest of the code for the page, or should I preferably be using an API to fetch this information on page load and temporarily store it? As of the moment the JSON file is 74kb's uncompressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using the default create-react-app configuration? If yes, you can use an async import.

```
function Component() {
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    import("./Assets/names/names.json").then(arrayOfNames => setList(arrayOfNames));
  }, []);

  return (
    <ul>
      {list.map(name => <li key={name}>{name}</li>)}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

This way, on default CRA configuration, webpack will generate two different bundles and will load the names bundle just when you load this component that calls it on the async `import(..)`.

Comment: Maybe you will need to use `setList(arrayOfNames.default)` instead of `setList(arrayOfNames)`

Comment: Yes, I'm using the default Create-React-App config. I hadn't thought to import it asynchronously! Thanks a bunch 